# Makefile delegate unknown rule to another makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile that builds another Makefile (call it Makefile.2) and I'd like to set it up so that if I run 'make foo' and Makefile does not have a foo rule that it will automatically try $(MAKE) -f Makefile.2 foo.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overriding-Makefiles

Comment: Thanks! This is great.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is very late, but for anyone stumbling on this question using Google I'll provide an answer.

You can make use of the trick @Gregory suggested in the comments, or achieve the same effect with a wildcard rule. It requires some tinkering, though.

From an answer to another question, I learned that *make* by default uses a hidden rule when no rule matches. Therefore, you have to explicitly disable this default rule for any file(s) you might be using in your first Makefile and that are required when forwarding. In my case, it was a `CMakeLists.txt` that was processed in the first `Makefile` before I forwarded to `Makefile.2`.

That's not all though. In my case, I had to disable all rules for the `Makefile` itself, for reasons I'm not sure about. Without this, the Makefile itself would be forwarded as a target to `Makefile.2`. Someone else will probably be able to explain this, but the important thing is it fixes the issue.

This is the result. If someone has suggestions for improvement, I'll update my answer.

```
# Custom rules can be added here.
#
# Just make sure to disable the default rule for any files
# your wildcard rule might also use or you'll end up with
# a circular dependency.

Makefile:;

.PHONY: %

%:
  $(MAKE) -f Makefile.2 $@
```

The file was tested on a macOS Mojave using GNUmake 3.81.